# UInt64 - Automation Type Not SUpported

Tags: vba, sha512

I'm trying to implement a SHA512 algorithm on VBA, Excel 2003.

This is what i'm using as a basis: http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/

I'm facing a problem with the use of UInt64 (unsigned long) in VBA. The following code throws the error: `Variable Uses an Automation Type Not Supported`.

```
Sub Main()
       Dim notworking As UInt64
End Sub
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned integer datatype isn't supported in vba. I think you might have a library for vb.net.